# Finding distance between lat-long coordiantes taking a long time R

Tags: r, runtime, geosphere

I currently have a dataframe (lang.py) in which I have pairs of latitude and longitude coordinates. I'm using the distHaversine() function from the geosphere package to do so.

This is a sample of my data (which has 25200 rows):
[image]

Originally I tried:

```
lang.py$distance = with(lang.py, distm(cbind(lon_x, lat_x), cbind(lon_y, lat_y), distHaversine))
```

But this was taking a long time to run so I attempted to look at the output of just the first 4 rows which was outputting a 4x4matrix of values rather than just a single column of the distance values so I assume for the entire dataset, my code was outputting a 25200x25200 matrix of distance values.

For example, this is what the first 4 rows were outputting:

```
with(lang.py[1:4,], distm(cbind(lon_x, lat_x), cbind(lon_y, lat_y), distHaversine))
```

[image]

To fix this, I attempted to take the diagonal of the matrix so get a single column of values:

```
lang.py$distance = diag(with(lang.py, distm(cbind(lon_x, lat_x), cbind(lon_y, lat_y), distHaversine)))
```

But this was also taking an extremely long time to run. Any ideas on how to make this more efficient? I am trying to find the distance between (lat_x, lon_x) and (lat_y, lon_y). Thanks

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Running `diag` on a long-running process still runs *all* of the long-running process and then filters out all except the diagonal elements. There's nothing to "inform" the inner code to only operate on specific elements.
2. Simpler than `diag` would have been the first row, since all numbers in each column (in this example) are identical.
3. If you look at the source code for `geosphere::distm`, you'll see that it is calculating the distance between the first row of the first argument (effectively `cbind(lon_x, lat_x)[1,]`) with all rows of the second argument; then the second row of the first arg with all rows of the second arg. The reason you are seeing a matrix of identical values within a column is that in the sample above, your `lon_x`/`lat_x` are all the same. This is producing a distance *matrix*, not the distance between two points at a time.

It seems that you don't need a distance *matrix*, you just need *distance*.

```r
with(lang.py, distHaversine(cbind(lon_x, lat_x), cbind(lon_y, lat_y)))
# [1]  4042785  5417756 13819986
```

This will calculate one distance for each row; there is no comparison of lat/lon on one row with lat/lon on another row ... and since you're looking at a `data.frame`, that makes sense to me.

---

Data, so that anybody else can try to work your code (this should be you providing it, not me):

```r
lang.py <- structure(list(lat_x = c(35, 35, 35), lon_x = c(66, 66, 66), lat_y = c(41, 36.5, -13.92), lon_y = c(20, 5, -171.83)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```